# Mapper and Reducer interfaces not considered

Tags: java, exception, hadoop, mapreduce, ubuntu-14.04

This is my mapper function header line

```
public static class PageMapper extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text>
```

and this is my Reducer function header

```
public static class PageReducer extends Reducer`<Text, Text, Text, Text>
```

While compiling the code

> PageRank.java:30: error: no interface expected here

```
    extends Mapper <Object, Text, Text, Text>
```

> PageRank.java:61: error: no interface expected here

```
public static class PageReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>
```

Why is it not accepting the Mapper and Reducer here. Can anyone help please

Comment: Please change "extends" to "implements" ...but then

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `Mapper` and `Reducer` are interfaces, not classes. You implement interfaces, not classes. Other than that, just keep in mind that both `Mapper` and `Reducer` interfaces implement Generics and expect two key-value pairs. Forexample:

```
Mapper<Key1,Value1,Key2,Value2>
```

You can read more about Mapper and Reducer from here:

[org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Mapper.html)

[org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Reducer.html)

Answer (score 0):

What is confusing is that the API contains both:
1) the ***class*** org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer
and
2) the ***interface*** org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer

AND

1) the class does not implement the interface
2) the method reduce in the class has a different signature from the interface
3) the MapReduce tutorial uses the class Reducer, and not the interface.

My guess is that one of the two should be deprecated and it should be mentioned somewhere what is the best practice: 1) to implement the interface org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer, or 2) to extend the class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer